# How to proper position skybox camera using openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, skybox

I created a skybox for my project and it looks the way I wanted it to; however, there are a few issues I cannot figure out how to fix and I have read some tutorials on this subject, but I was not able to find something that would help me.
The first problem is that I don't know how to get the box to always move with my camera. In the image below you can see that I am able to zoom out and see the whole box, instead of only zooming in/out of the solar system and always having the stars on the background.

[image]

The other issue I have is that when I zoom in too close my background disappears.The picture below illustrates what I mean
[image]

I know if I can get the camera working properly I can get this fixed, but it goes back to my first problem. I don't know how to access the camera info.

I believe I would have to modify `glTranslatef()` and `glScalef()` in my code from a fixed number to a number that changes with the camera position. 
Here is my code:

```
void Skybox::displaySkybox() 
{

Images::RGBImage test[6]; //6 pictures for 6 sides
test[0]=Images::readImageFile(fileName); //Top
//test[1]=Images::readImageFile(fileName);//Back
//test[2]=Images::readImageFile(fileName);//Bottom
//test[3]=Images::readImageFile(fileName);//Right
//test[4]=Images::readImageFile(fileName); //Left
//test[5]=Images::readImageFile(fileName);  //Front

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
test[0].glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB);

// Save Current Matrix
glPushMatrix();

// Second Move the render space to the correct position (Translate)
glTranslatef(0,0,0);

// First apply scale matrix
glScalef(10000,10000,10000);

 static const GLint faces[6][4] =
                {
                {5, 1, 2, 6}, // back
                {5, 4, 0, 1}, // bottom
                {0, 4, 7, 3}, // front
                {4, 5, 6, 7}, // right ( 'left' in crinity's labeling )
                {1, 0, 3, 2}, // left  ( 'right' in crinity's labeling )
                {2, 3, 7, 6}  // top*/
                };
GLfloat v[8][3];
GLint i;

v[0][0] = v[1][0] = v[2][0] = v[3][0] = -1;  // min x
v[4][0] = v[5][0] = v[6][0] = v[7][0] =  1;  // max x
v[0][1] = v[1][1] = v[4][1] = v[5][1] = -1;  // min y
v[2][1] = v[3][1] = v[6][1] = v[7][1] =  1;  // max y
v[0][2] = v[3][2] = v[4][2] = v[7][2] = -1;  // min z
v[1][2] = v[2][2] = v[5][2] = v[6][2] =  1;  // max z

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
{
    //
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f(0,1);  glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][0]][0]);
glTexCoord2f(1,1);  glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][1]][0]);
glTexCoord2f(1,0);  glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][2]][0]);
glTexCoord2f(0,0);  glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][3]][0]);

    glEnd();
}
// Load Saved Matrix
glPopMatrix();

}
```

How can I get access to these variables? Does openGL alreay have a function that takes care of that?

Comment: A good I guess is to make a camera class so you can separate its rotation and translation. Make it very simple first, then you can expand on it later.

Comment: Is this the actual `displaySkybox()` function you call every frame meaning that you load the texture every single frame?

Comment: yeah... should I do it differently?

Comment: I don't know is this `RGBImage` class is doing something fancy, but to me it seems like your code is loading the image file from disk and you recreate the texture every frame. You should only load, set parameters and `glTexImage` at initialization.

Answer (score 11):

> I believe I would have to modify glTranslatef() and glScalef() in my code from a fixed number to a number that changes with the camera position.

You're close, but there's a simpler solution:

1. Draw the skybox first, before translating the camera, so that you don't have to translate the box. Don't forget to clear your depth buffer for each new frame (you'll see why in a second).
2. Disable writes to the depth buffer (call `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)`). This will cause every other object you render to draw over it, making it always appear "behind" everything else.
3. Assuming your transform matrices were reset at the start of the frame, apply only the *rotation* of the camera. This way the camera will always be "centered" inside the box.
4. Draw the skybox. Since writes to the depth buffer are off, it doesn't matter how small it is as long as it's larger than your camera's near clip plane.
5. Re-enable writes to the depth buffer (call `glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)`)
6. Render your scene normally.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Step 3 is what I don't know how to do. I understand the camera has to be always centered inside the box, but I don't know how to do it. The `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)` didn't really do anything to my program.

Comment: For step 3, just take your usual camera transform and zero out the translation componenets (see http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/#Translation_matrices if you're not sure which ones those are.)

Comment: Then how are you currently controlling movement in your application? The "camera" is just whatever transform you apply to the model/view matrix before you begin to apply the transforms for each object's location in world-space

Comment: That's why I was wondering if openGL has a function that would give me access to the camera's components.

Comment: Assuming Vrui is using the fixed function pipeline and not shaders, you can access the model/view matrix with `glGetFloatv`, using `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX`. then set it with `glLoadMatrixf`.

Comment: I got what the `glDepthMask` function does. It works. The glGet and glLoad I tried using but it didn't help. I'm trying to figure out a way to make my skybox work properly. Thanks anyways for the help. Sorry I don't really understand much about this.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't worked with skyboxes before, but it would make sense that the camera should always be at the center of the box. So start by translating the box to center around the camera coordinates, something like `glTranslate(camera.x, camera.y, camera.z);` 
Then I'd think the box should stay infinitely distant, so maybe set the vertices to INT_MAX or something ridonculously big.

```
v[0][0] = v[1][0] = v[2][0] = v[3][0] = -INT_MAX;  // min x
v[4][0] = v[5][0] = v[6][0] = v[7][0] =  INT_MAX;  // max x ...etc
```

Then probably get rid of the call to glScalef(). Try that out

Comment: Firstly, the vertices are floats, so `INT_MAX` doesn't make sense here. Secondly, the correct solution is to disable writes to the depth buffer while you draw the sky box, making it appear "infinitely" far away. You draw the box first, before applying translations.